# Need explanations on families of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, predicate-logic

I am currently reading Naive Set Theory by P. R. Halmos and am quite stumped with the notation used to define a family of sets. E.g, given "a family $\{x_{i}\}$ in $X$". What exactly does this mean? What is $\{x_{i}\}$? Intuitively, I came to the conclusion that $\{x_{i}\}$ is a set of all the elements in $X$ indexed by some set $I$. Am I correct? And, if I am, wouldn't the range of the family function given in the example be equal to $\{x_{i}\}$? Also, is there any standard way to denote a family as a lowercase roman letter, similar to other function denotations?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. Halmos defines $x$ as a function from an indexing set $I$ to the set $X$. Intuitively, this means that we take an element from $X$, not necessarily unique, for each element of $I$. Compare this notion to the definition of a sequence you probably learned in your second semester calculus course.

Comment: Is there any way to speak of a family by denoting it as a function? In that case, what denotation could we use? And after denoting the said family in the form of a traditional function, say ƒ for now, would I be right if I said that  {xᵢ} = ranƒ?

Comment: @Camelot823 Yes. The term $x_i$ is equivalent to $x(i)$ in traditional function notation so the $\{x_i\}$ can be viewed as the range of the function $x$.

Comment: By "family $\{x_i\}$ in $X$" Halmos usually means the function $x:I\to X$, not the range. He specifically comments on this "unacceptable" notation at the beginning of Section 9 of the book.